# Where is the documentation for ATG Dynamo?

Tags: atg-dynamo

Can anyone explain find a link to a pdf of any documentation at all that's online?

I have tried every search I can think of and have poured though many pages on Oracle's site. I asked more senior engineers at work for docs and links and have come up with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Found this after googling. Hope this helps:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGProgGuide/html/s0901coredynamoservices01.html

Also need to write more than 30 chars to able to post this.

Comment: In my defense, I still can't find this via Google and this question is now the 3rd link for "ATG Dynamo Documentation"

Comment: Searched for "ATG Dynamo oracle"